# Finding out the number of times innermost loop will iterate using combinations

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Whenever I try to search for this question I seem to find methods using summations, but according to book I can do this with combinations? The book gives me two examples of two different situations on how to set up the combination, then gives me a general formula which I believe would be too easy to apply?

when you have a loop situation like

```
for i:=1 to n
     for j:=1 to i
       for k:=1 to j
```

$$1\le k\le j\le k \le n$$

Then it is concluded that the generalized formula is $$C(n-1+r,r)$$ where r is the number of nested loops

I'm guessing this is only for the situation above as right now I am dealing with

```
for k:=1 to n-1
 for j:=1 to k+1
```

and I have no clue how to come up with the expression for the combination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do the sums.

$$  \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=1}^{k+1} 1 = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k+1 = \frac{1}{2}(n+2)(n-1)  \text{.}  $$

$$  \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i \sum_{k=1}^j 1 = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^i j = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2}i(i+1) = \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(n+2)  \text{.}  $$

Notice that the second one is $\frac{(n+2)!}{(n-1)! 3!} = C(n+2,3)$, as provided.  But the first one does not have consecutive multiplicands; it is not a single binomial coefficient.

Comment: In the first example you worked on, how did you move from the middle of the equation to the final answer on the right side? It seems like you split the $k+1$, would isn't the summation  for k, $(n-1(n))/2$ not sure how to get rid of the leading n.

Comment: @Jude : $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k+1 = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 1 = \left(\frac{1}{2}(n-1)n \right) + (n-1) = \frac{(n-1)n + 2(n-1)}{2}  \text{.}  $$